# Has Donald Trump made any statements that are considered homophobic?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, bernie-sanders

Bernie Sanders has stated multiple times that Donald Trump is a homophobic. Have there been any instances of him making homophobic comments or policies?

Comment: I'm voting to close, because it's a question about motivation, which we can't answer here ([see also here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3848)). Questions we could answer would eg be "Has the Trump administration strengthened or weakened LGBT anti-discrimination laws?" (it [weakened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_policy_of_Donald_Trump#LGBT_anti-discrimination_laws) them; see also [here](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/dominicholden/trump-lgbt-anti-actions-administration-pride-month)).

Comment: Why not edit it to ask whether he's made any statements that are prejudiced against LBGT people? Or whether his policies harm them? These would be two valid questions, and I have some particularly good examples for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The question body asks about both statements and policy. Now, obviously, anti-gay policies and homophobic comments don't always go hand-in-hand. However, there are a few possible examples of both.

### Policies

There are various examples, but here are a few.

- Trump has emphasized (or allowed his vice president to emphasize) [religious freedom guidelines](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/religious-liberty-task-force-jeff-sessions-trump-department-of-justice-a8470581.html) that seem primarily designed to allow Christians to discriminate against lesbian and gay customers. In many cases, these guidelines are superfluous, since existing law in many [cases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece_Cakeshop_v._Colorado_Civil_Rights_Commission) permits such discrimination, leading to concerns that these guidelines will even *encourage* it.
- His Justice Department has also [argued in court against](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/trump-fire-gay-workers/) anti-discrimination protections for gay employees.
- He also seems to have taken a weaker tack on defending LBGT rights abroad. Although he has, say, formed groups to fight the criminalization of being non-straight overseas, he has been, at the least, inconstant in this regard. For instance, under his government, the US voted against a [resolution condemning the death penalty for homosexuality](https://www.undispatch.com/us-vote-un-resolution-condemning-execution-gay-people/).

An honorable mention also for Trump's [ban on transgender people serving in the military.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.bbc.com/news/amp/world-us-canada-46963426) While this isn't directly anti-gay, it's certainly anti-LBGT. Indeed, Trump's anti-transgender policy has often been more personal and overt than his anti-gay policy.

### Comments

Although Trump has not said as many nasty things about GLB people as about his more favored targets, such as women, Muslims, black people and Mexicans, he may have said a few.

- His lawyer, Michael Cohen, [claims](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.foxnews.com/politics/micahel-cohen-alleges-racist-comments-by-trump-in-private-conversations.amp) that Donald used an anti-gay slur in a private conversation.
- In 2011, he [expressed his opposition to gay marriage](http://www.towleroad.com/2011/02/trump-4/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20towleroad%2Ffeed%20%28Towleroad%20Daily%20%20%23gay%20news%29), as well as asserting that New York was a "place with a lot of gays":

  > "No, I'm just not in favor of gay marriage. I live in New York. New York is a place with lots of gays, and I think it is great. But I'm not in favor of gay marriage."
- Elaborating on this, he later described his opposition to marriage equality thus, according to the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/02/nyregion/after-roasting-trump-reacts-in-character.html):

  > "It's like in golf," he said. "A lot of people-I don't want this to sound trivial-but a lot of people are switching to these really long putters, very unattractive," said Trump. "It's weird. You see these great players with these really long putters, because they can't sink three-footers anymore. And, I hate it. I am a traditionalist. I have so many fabulous friends who happen to be gay, but I am a traditionalist."